# Hiding an ImageButton on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, imagebutton

I have two ImageButtons on my page. Upon clicking one, I want to hide it and display the other. My current code is:

```
var button_mute = document.getElementsByID("ImageButtonMute");
var button_unmute = document.getElementsByID("ImageButtonUnmute");

    function mute() {
        vid_left.mute();
        vid_right.mute();

        button_mute.style.display = "block";
        button_unmute.style.display = "none";
    }

    function unmute() {
        vid_left.unMute();
        vid_right.unMute();

        button_mute.style.display = "none";
        button_unmute.style.display = "block";
    }


<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonMute" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/icons/volume_mute_small.png" OnClientClick="mute()" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonUnmute" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/icons/volume_unmute_small.png" OnClientClick="unmute()" />
```

I haven't referenced either in the code behind, and I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you put the javascript in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: document.getElementsByID != document.getElementByID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this select:

```
var button_mute = document.getElementsByID('<%= ImageButtonMute.ClientID %>');
var button_unmute = document.getElementsByID('<%= ImageButtonUnmute.ClientID %>');
```

This should work!